Recent app list display two app while open from the notification in flutter
I'm creating an app in Flutter. I have faced issues for the last few days.
I create notifications using AlarmService. When clicking on the generated notification, it opens the app.
Close the app via the back button and don't remove it from the recent app list. now I open the app from the App Icon. Recent app history display to apps.
I'm also doing this solution but it's not working for me. android:launchMode="singleTop"
activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">


For Closing app via back button
PopScope(
      canPop:canPopNow,
      onPopInvokedWithResult: (didPop, result) {
        if (0 < controller.currentIndex.value) {
          canPopNow=false;
          controller.changePage(0);
        } else {
          DateTime now = DateTime.now();
          if (_lastPressedAt == null || now.difference(_lastPressedAt!) > Duration(seconds: 2)) {
            _lastPressedAt = now;
            VxToast.show(context, msg: "Please click BACK again to exit",textColor: Colors.black,bgColor: Colors.grey.shade300.withAlpha(128),showTime: 800);
            // print("Press again to exit $_lastPressedAt  --  $now");
            // print("Press again to exit ${now.difference(_lastPressedAt!).inSeconds } ==== ${Duration(seconds: 2).inSeconds}");
            canPopNow = false;
          }else{
            SystemNavigator.pop();
            canPopNow = true;
          }
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(


I am quoting this answer. To see if it is suitable to resolve your case:
Can you try this one?

If you only want one task to show up in the list of recent tasks, then
you need to set the following on the other  tags in the
manifest:
android:excludeFromRecents="true"

Update
PopScope<Object?>(
  canPop: false,
  onPopInvokedWithResult: (bool didPop, Object? result) async {
    if (didPop) {
      return;
    }
    final bool shouldPop = await _onPop() ?? false;
    if (context.mounted && shouldPop) {
      SystemNavigator
        .pop(); // to allow the user to return on the device app stack
    }
},
child: Scaffold(
  body: Widget here...

Code explanation: before the app is closed, use this code SystemNavigator.pop(); and make sure that it is executing properly. I provided PopScope code snippet just to demonstrate how I resolved that issue using dart code.
Now see how it behaves in your app.
I hope it helps!

It works as per your answer but I also want the app in the recent list.

I've updated my answer just now. Let's see if it resolves your case.

I update my code. I've already used SystemNavigator.pop();  for the closing App.

Then, what happened next?

I don't know where I made a mistake and how this issue happened.

Why don't you include in your post how the notification channel handles redirection to your app? It could attract more potential answers. Also, read this as a guide in constructing your question.
